# Is the Sonoff RF bridge slow?

Tags: smart-home, sonoff

I have a [Sonoff RF bridge](https://sonoff.itead.cc/en/products/appliances/sonoff-rf-bridge-433) flashed with [ESPurna](https://github.com/xoseperez/espurna) which works fine but there is a ~1 second delay between the moment I press in the ESPurna web interface the switch button, and when the action is actually performed.

On the other side is a "[smart plug](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/5pcs-Wireless-Power-Switch-Sockets-1-Remote-Controller-Home-Mains-EU-Plug-Hot-Promotion/32623575846.html)". When switching it on/off with the associated remote, the reaction is immediate (I tried to send the signal next to the bridge to make sure obstacles do not interfere unfairly).

Could it be that the the RF bridge is simply slow to send the message (which is unfortunate but not the end of the world either), or are there tweaks I could test in order to speed this up?

**Device information**

```
[094378] [MAIN] ESPURNA 1.13.3a
[094379] [MAIN] xose.perez@gmail.com
[094380] [MAIN] http://tinkerman.cat

[094381] [MAIN] CPU chip ID: 0x8250D4
[094382] [MAIN] CPU frequency: 80 MHz
[094384] [MAIN] SDK version: 1.5.3(aec24ac9)
[094385] [MAIN] Core version: 2.3.0
[094386] [MAIN] Core revision: 159542381
[094387] 
[094389] [MAIN] Flash chip ID: 0x144051
[094392] [MAIN] Flash speed: 40000000 Hz
[094394] [MAIN] Flash mode: DOUT
[094395] 
[094396] [MAIN] Flash size (CHIP)   :  1048576 bytes /  256 sectors (   0 to  255)
[094399] [MAIN] Flash size (SDK)    :  1048576 bytes /  256 sectors (   0 to  255)
[094400] [MAIN] Reserved            :     4096 bytes /    1 sectors (   0 to    0)
[094402] [MAIN] Firmware size       :   450704 bytes /  111 sectors (   1 to  111)
[094403] [MAIN] Max OTA size        :   569344 bytes /  139 sectors ( 112 to  250)
[094404] [MAIN] EEPROM size         :     4096 bytes /    1 sectors ( 251 to  251)
[094406] [MAIN] Reserved            :    16384 bytes /    4 sectors ( 252 to  255)
[094407] 
[094408] [MAIN] EEPROM sectors: 251, 250
[094410] [MAIN] EEPROM current: 250
[094411] 
[094412] [MAIN] EEPROM:  4096 bytes total -  2064 bytes used (50%) -  2032 bytes free (49%)
[094414] [MAIN] Heap  : 38808 bytes total - 25048 bytes used (64%) - 13760 bytes free (35%)
[094416] [MAIN] Stack :  4096 bytes total -  1488 bytes used (36%) -  2608 bytes free (63%)
[094418] 
[094419] [MAIN] Boot version: 6
[094420] [MAIN] Boot mode: 1
[094424] [MAIN] Last reset reason: Power on
[094427] [MAIN] Last reset info: flag: 0
[094429] 
[094430] [MAIN] Board: ITEAD_SONOFF_RFBRIDGE
[094432] [MAIN] Support: API BROKER BUTTON DEBUG_TELNET DEBUG_WEB LED MDNS_SERVER MQTT NTP SCHEDULER TELNET TERMINAL WEB 
[094433] [MAIN] WebUI image: RFBRIDGE
[094435] 
[094436] [MAIN] Firmware MD5: 364173c2f02e62693792f6614b6d00b3
[094438] [MAIN] Power: 3196 mV
[094439] [MAIN] Power saving delay value: 10 ms
[094441]
```

*Note: the question was [originally raised](https://github.com/xoseperez/espurna/issues/1449) as an "issue" in ESPurna Github repo.*